# Check if a type belongs to a namespace without hardcoded strings

Tags: c#

Is it possible to check if a type is part of a namespace without using harcoded strings?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
Type type = typeof(System.Data.Constraint);
if(type.Namespace == System.Data.ToString())
{...}
```

or

```
Type type = typeof(System.Data.Constraint);
if(type.Namespace == System.Data)
{...}
```

to avoid

```
Type type = typeof(System.Data.Constraint);
if(type.Namespace == "System.Data")
{...}
```

These examples don't compile but should give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

I can't use `nameof(System.Data)` because it only returns `"Data"`.

I would like to find a way to check if a class if part of a namespace without the need to have that namespace in a string.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is something like String.Join(".",nameof(System), nameof(System.Data)). Ugly but still kind of do what you want :)

Comment: What's the difference between hardcoding a string and (eventually) hardcoding a namespace?

Comment: Though I'm interested why there is no such thing like a `NamespaceInfo` class in reflection. I don't fully understand _why_ you need that here? Why no string? From where do you get the information that you want to compare to `type.Namespace`? If it's known at compile time, why no string?

Comment: There is a difference. For example if you moved all classes to difference namespace - nameof(namespace) won't compile any more. Also if you rename namespace with (for example) Resharper - it will rename all nameof(namespace) references also.

Comment: @codroipo Refactoring.  If the OP renames a namespace refactoring tools will update the code, but not if a string is used.

Comment: @juharr I would like to know what is that refactoring tool. If I have in 2(or more) different files something like `namespace SOMETHING{/**/}` and I change the namespace in one file, will it change the namespace everywhere? I hope not!

Comment: @codroipo It will give you the option of changing it everywhere, but does not do it automatically.  This is an option in more recent versions of VS and has been a part of Resharper for even longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define this in the namespace where you want to perform the check:

```
static class Namespace
{
    public static bool Contains<T>() 
        => typeof (T).Namespace == typeof (Namespace).Namespace;
}
```

For example:

```
namespace My.Inner
{
    static class Namespace
    {
        public static bool Contains<T>()
            => typeof (T).Namespace == typeof (Namespace).Namespace;
    }    
}
```

Two types as test cases:

```
namespace My
{
    class SomeTypeA { }
}

namespace My.Inner
{
    class SomeTypeB { }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(My.Inner.Namespace.Contains<SomeTypeA>()); // False
Console.WriteLine(My.Inner.Namespace.Contains<SomeTypeB>()); // True
```

Comment: This limits the Contains method to a single namespace, so you'd need to replicate each class for example at "System.Data" and "System.IO"

Comment: @cFrozenDeath True, it's rather limited. The problem is that there are no namespaces in the CLR, only types with dots in their names. So one way or another you need to put something you can reference in that namespace if you *must* avoid using a string.

Comment: See the edit on my answer, it should be the best we can make without hardcoding strings.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
static class Namespaces
{
    //You would then need to add a prop for each namespace you want
    static string Data = typeof(System.Data.Constrains).Namespace;
}

var namespaceA = typeof(System.Data.DataTable).Namespace
if (namespaceA == Namespaces.Data) //true
{ 
    //do something
}
```

Also, using the idea from **@Theodoros Chatzigiannakis**, you could further generalize this:

```
static class Namespace
{
    //generic
    static bool Contains<T1, T2>()
    {
        return typeof(T1).Namespace == typeof(T2).Namespace;
    }
    //Non-generic
    static bool Contains(Type type1, Type type2)
    {
        return type1.Namespace == type2.Namespace;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
bool generic = Namespace.Contains<System.Data.CLASS1, System.Data.CLASS2>();
bool nonGeneric = Namespace.Contains(typeof(System.Data.CLASS1), typeof(System.Data.CLASS2));
```

Comment: I want to check if a class is part of a namespace, not if two classes are part of the same namespace. Not sure if it was clear from my question....

Comment: Thanks for the help and ideas. Still not what I was looking for. I have just one class, that I want to check if it's in a specific namespace. You are comparing namespaces of two classes.

Comment: @Dante my second code does just that, or you are not clear enough